# Windows URL scheme call to running program

Tags: windows, ipc, url-scheme, xojo

I want to trigger an event in my running application and deliver arguments with the call of a URL scheme in Windows 10.
I made the following registry entry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
alert
    (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
    URL Protocol = ""
    DefaultIcon
        (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
    shell
        open
            command
                (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```

Obviously, this always starts a new instance of my application with an argument, when calling 'alert:arg1'. But I want Windows to call my already running instance.

With Mac, the call of this URL scheme triggers an event, I can catch. Exactly, as I want. To do this, I added the following part to alert.app/Contents/Info.plist:

```
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>Alert</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
            <string>alert</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
```

So how do I realise this on Windows? I'm programming this application in XOJO with object-oriented BASIC, but I'll be happy about a general solution.

Comment: Windows simply relaunches the executable so your question is really "how to do IPC on Windows".  I don't know what you stack supports but this is generally accomplished by having the exe try to create a named mutex when it loads, if it can't it knows another instance of itself is running at which point it uses an IPC mechanism so forward its command line, by sending over a named pipe for example.

Comment: Make your application single-instance (the de facto way is using a Mutex) and send a message from the newly started instance to the already-running one, then exit.

Comment: Thanks to Alex and CodeCaster for leading me the right way. With this information I found a good article with working code and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after reading the answer of Alex, I searched how to realise this with code and found a well explained and working [solution](https://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/842) from Brad Smith written in C#.

The registry entry above can stay as it is, but the program also    needs:

> - A service class (which is exposed by the application instance
>     via .NET remoting)
> - A modified entry point (which will either    communicate with the service and then terminate, or start the    application normally)

Read his article and look at his code for further explanation.